# Get URL of page requested that caused a 404

Tags: jsp

How would I get the URL of the page that was requested that caused the 404 error?

For example, I type I go to http://example.com/path/does/not/exist/index.jsp
I already have a custom 404 page but how would I go about retrieving the URL mentioned above so that I can display it with a message similar to "The url http://example.com/path/does/not/exist/index.jsp does not exist"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSP / Servlet HTTP 404 error handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336501/jsp-servlet-http-404-error-handling)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If forward was used to go to the error page, you can obtain the original request URL by

```
request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")
```

or by EL

```
${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking more for like the example I gave, without forwarding

Comment: Indeed, an `<error-page>` is per definition shown by a forward.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks, I hadn't realized that it's forwarded to the 404 page. @Bozho Worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: From Tomcat 10 onwards it's jakarta.servlet.forward.request_uri

Answer (score 0):

I'm using JDK 8 and GlassFish 4, and

```
request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")
```

always returned null for me. What eventually did work was

```
request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri")
```

I'm not sure why the attribute name is different, but in case the name I listed doesn't work on your setup, here's the code I used to find it...

```
    Enumeration<String> names = request.getAttributeNames();

    while(names.hasMoreElements()){
        String name = names.nextElement();
        Object attr = request.getAttribute(name);

        System.out.println("Req:  "+name + " : "+attr);
    }
```

Comment: This was for a project I worked on many years ago but thank you for the update!