# Get original url for 404 page

Tags: php

So I have found these two questions:

[Accessing original URL in IIS7 404 redirect page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070695/accessing-original-url-in-iis7-404-redirect-page)
[Get URL of page requested that caused a 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948275/get-url-of-page-requested-that-caused-a-404)

but they are both in different languages. Is there any way to get the address that caused something like a 404 message to use in a custom message?

for example if I requested `example.com/example1` and that page wasn't there and it redirected to my error page, how could I get `example1` to display in a message like `The page`example1`isn't there`, or use that to create the page `example1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't it be in $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] variable?

See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: I have encountered the same problem,use referer is not always work,it depends,sometimes,all the server header values will lost,when redirect to error page.

Comment: @jan-tojnar These solutions don't work!  If I ask for $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] it is always blank and $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] gives the current script name not the error url.  

If a user types http://www.domain.com/nosuchfile.php and the .htaccess file points the 404 error as follows:
    ErrorDocument 404 http://www.domain.com/pagenotfound.php
then $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] contains http://www.domain.com/pagenotfound.php

Comment: @Chiwda if you redirect to the error page, `REQUEST_URI` will of course contain the address of the error page. You can try using relative path in `ErrorDocument` directive, which won't cause redirect.

Comment: OK.  That seems to be working...  
ErrorDocument 404 /pagenotfound.php

Comment: does not work on my webserver referer is empty - possibly its a ajaxrequest... did not figure it out yet.

Comment: ok - maybe you have a look at $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] if exist (might be depending on the installed server / configuration of "how" a error 404 is directed to the php-page.)

Answer (score 7):

Since you are using PHP, you would be having access to the various PHP superglobals.  $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] etc can be used for the purpose. Something like this in the error page should do:

```
<?php
    printf("The page %s was not found.", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
?>
```

For more, do have a look at the [$_SERVER superglobal documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).