# How to get refereed URL after redirect to 404 page in HTACCESS

Tags: php, .htaccess

My HTACCESS code is this

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

It is working well. What I want is when some one types a bad URL like (www.website.com/sometest.html)

In the case that "sometest.html" page does not exit and it will re-direct to the 404 page.
But how can I detect what URL they typed? I want to get this: www.website.com/sometest.html

I have tried `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];` both can't get the output that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Apache sets some environment variables for you. They were nice enough to let you know about it [in the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/custom-error.html).

Try using `$_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"]` and `$_SERVER["REDIRECT_QUERY"]` in your script.

Comment: like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666079/get-original-url-for-404-page

$_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"] worked for me. others where telling to use the referer but this is depending on the browser does send a referer and the server uses a location-header to redirect to the 404 page..