# getRequestURL() of HttpServletRequest not returning exact URL

Tags: java, tomcat

I am running a spring framework based web app on Tomcat. My requirement is that any request coming to the server should come to a single servlet. so i made the following configuration in conf/web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/displayMsg.do</location>
</error-page>
```

So when the user access http://myhost/xyz , request.getRequestURL() returns
http://myhost/displayMsg.do

I think the only reason for the requestURL() to return this url is because of the the error page configuration i made. May be because tomcat overwriting the url to this string.

Is it possible to get the exact URL in this case?
Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSP / Servlet HTTP 404 error handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336501/jsp-servlet-http-404-error-handling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same problem a couple weeks ago.

You can pull the actual url using

request.getAttribute(\"javax.servlet.forward.request_uri\").toString()

Comment: Yep, this returns the uri. request.getRequestURL() gives the http://localhost string. Concatenation of both these string helps.
Thank you.